# trouble understanding classes objects and constructors

Tags: java, class, object, methods, constructor

im having trouble understanding classes and how constructors work . (this is in java)
I have to create  a class called Complex that manipulates the complex numbers and this class is going to have the variables realPart and ImaginaryPart type double. now if c1 and c2 are objects of type Complex then if i do c1.add(c2) it should return Complex object that is the sum of the two objects. however this is the part where im stuck at i dont know how to add this two numbers?

So far i have done this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Complex c1 = new Complex(2, 8);
    Complex c2 = new Complex(2.3, 5.4);
    Complex c3 = c1.add(c2);
   Complex c4 = Complex.add(c1,c2);

}
```

}

class Complex {

```
private double realPart;
private double imaginaryPart;

public Complex() {

}

public Complex(double c1, double c2) {
    realPart = c1;
    imaginaryPart = c2;

}

public void setValue(int numberOne) {
    realPart = numberOne;
}

public Complex add(Complex other) {
    Complex result = new Complex();
    this.realPart = 3;
    return result;

}

public Complex subtract(Complex other) {
    Complex result = new Complex();
    this.realPart = 5;

    return result;
}

public String toString() {

    return c1.add(c2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
public Complex add(Complex other) {
    Complex result = new Complex();
    result.realPart = this.realPart + other.realPart;
    result.imaginaryPart = this.imaginaryPart + other.imaginaryPart;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Work out the values you want inside your new `Complex` first, then use `new` to make your new `Complex`, based on those values.  Lastly, use `return` to make your new `Complex` the value returned by the method call.

This is one way to implement it, but not the only way.  Note that when you write `realPart` without specifying the object that you want to find the real part of, it will be the `realPart` from the current object - the one before the dot in the method call.  In other words, it's the same as writing `this.realPart`.

```
public Complex add(Complex other) {
    double realPartOfResult = realPart + other.realPart;
    double imaginaryPartOfResult = imaginaryPart + other.imaginaryPart;
    Complex result = new Complex(realPartOfResult, imaginaryPartOfResult);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you will execute : `c1.Add(c2)`, your `"this"` will be the `Complex` Object c1

```
public Complex add(Complex other) {
    Complex result = new Complex();
    double realResult = this.realPart + other.realPart;
    double imaginaryResult = this.imaginaryPart + other.imaginaryPart;
    result.realPart = realResult;
    result.imaginaryPart = imaginaryResult;
    return result;
}
```

Same way about the `Substruct` method

```
public Complex subtract(Complex other) {
    Complex result = new Complex();
    double realResult = this.realPart - other.realPart;
    double imaginaryResult = this.imaginaryPart - other.imaginaryPart;
    result.realPart = realResult;
    result.imaginaryPart = imaginaryResult;
    return result;
}
```

I advice you reading :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html